# Cambiar un número de caracteres aleatorios

Tags: python, random

Estoy intentando crear una función que haga un número de modificaciones aleatorias en una cadena dada, formada por una serie de caracteres que conocemos previamente.

Por ejemplo, sea la cadena: `'ABCDDDDDAABBBAABABCDBAB'`, entre los caracteres que pueden ser cambiados es un conjunto `l = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}`.

Había pensado en crear una función que lleve como parámetros el número de cambios aleatorios que se quieren hacer y la cadena sobre la que hacer los cambio.

Algo como esto:

```
import random
def cambios(numero, cadena):
    cadena = ''
    l = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}
    for i in cadena:
        resultado = cadena.random.choice(l)
   return cadena
while True:
cadena = input('Introduzca cadena:')
numero = int(input('Introduzca numero de cambios:'))
if cadena == 'q':
    break
print('La cadena cambiada es:', cambios(numero, cadena))
```

La salida debería ser algo como esto:
Si la cadena de entrada es `'ABCDAA'` y el usuario mete 2 cambios para esa cadena en una posición aleatoria, la salida debería ser por ejemplo: `'ABBDAD'`. En este caso han cambiado las posiciones 2 y 5 de forma aleatoria.

La cadena solo va a estar formada por elementos que forman parte del conjunto, y las substituciones solo se pueden llevar por elementos que forman parte del conjunto. En otra función ya tengo definido que la cadena solo va a estar formada por elementos del conjunto establecido.

Comment: Hola Steve, para aclararme un poco quieres que dada una cadena y un numero de sustituciones se realicen esas sustituciones por alguno de los caracteres del conjunto `l`. Bien, ¿los caracteres que pueden ser substituidos son cualquiera de la cadena o solo si ese carácter está en el conjunto `l`? Es decir, si en tu ejemplo ingresas "ABJA" es posible que la "J" se intercambie por alguna letra del conjunto `l` si su indice es elegido al azar?

Comment: LA cadena solo va a estar formada por elementos que forman parte del conjunto, y las substituciones solo se pueden llevar por elementos que forman parte del conjunto. En otra funcion ya tengo definido que la cadena solo va a estar formada por elementos del conjunto establecido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que hay que destacar es que `random.choice` no funciona con conjuntos, el iterable debe permitir indexación.

Por otro lado, en tu función sobreescribes el argumento cadena pasando a ser una cadena vacía, lo cual no va a funcionar. Dado que la concatenación de cadenas es poco eficiente y más difícil de manejar, un opción es pasar la cadena a una lista y una vez hechos los cambios oportunos se reconstruye la cadena con `str.join`.

Una posibilidad es:

```
import random

def cambios(numero, cadena):
    cadena = list(cadena)
    l = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
    for i in random.choices(range(len(cadena)), k = numero):
        cadena[i] = random.choice(l)
    return "".join(cadena)

while True:
    cadena = input('Introduzca cadena: ')
    numero = int(input('Introduzca numero de cambios: '))
    if cadena == 'q':
        break
    print('La cadena cambiada es: ', cambios(numero, cadena))
```

Téngase en cuenta que se puede dar la situación en la que un carácter sea sustituido por si mismo. Es decir, si tenemos la cadena "ABC" puede darse que se elija aleatoriamente la el segundo carácter para ser substituido y y que por azar también salga la "B" elegida para sustituirla. Si queremos evitar esta posibilidad podemos hacer algo como:

```
def cambios(numero, cadena):
    cadena = list(cadena)
    l = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}
    for i in random.choices(range(len(cadena)), k = numero):
        cadena[i] = random.sample(l-{cadena[i]},  k = 1).pop()
    return "".join(cadena)
```

Usando la diferencia de conjuntos nos aseguramos que el carácter a sustituir no pueda salir elegido como para substituirse a si mismo.